# Launch a process during start up that uses dbus in Linux

Tags: linux, dbus

I have to start a process during the start up in Linux(Ubuntu Linux). This process uses dbus session bus. I tried by adding this process in the bashrc and etc/rc.local file. I even tried the start up programs/applications in Ubuntu. But that does not seems to work.Can you please help me in fixing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally the start up applications in ubunutu worked for me, Initially I was using the script with some arguments. That is why it was not working before.